# Can I parse a multipart/mixed response without having to convert it into a string first?

Tags: angular, typescript, parsing, pdf, multipart

I'm receiving a `multipart/mixed` response over HTTP, which contains some JSON data as well as PDFs in byte format. Since Angular cannot handle such responses naively, my current approach is to convert the response into a string using the `responseType: 'text'` option.

I then take the response apart, parse the JSON, and put the PDF data into a blob like this:

```
let pdf: Blob = new Blob([new TextEncoder().encode(bytestring)], { type: 'application/pdf' });
```

However, when I want to create a download link for the PDF with `window.URL.createObjectURL(pdf)`, the downloaded PDF is damaged and can't be opened.

I have confirmed that when Angular turns the response into a string, it uses UTF-8 encoding. I also implemented a separate route so I can request a single PDF on its own, allowing me to use `responseType: 'blob'`, which works and downloads a functioning PDF. Furthermore, I forced VS Code to open both the original PDF file as well as the damaged one and the representation of the bytes is identical.

Since I'm able to transfer a functioning PDF when not sending it as part of a multipart request, it seems to me that the only possible cause for the broken PDF is the way I parse the multipart request, and I have read elsewhere that converting a PDF into a string and then back into a PDF can be problematic. So, is there any way to do this without converting it into a string?

Comment: Hint: you should _never_ need to convert anything into a string first (including those horrible megabyte-sized Base64 `data:` URIs...).

Comment: PDFs are a binary file format - they aren't "UTF-8" - I'm not sure where you're getting that from..

Comment: _"Since Angular cannot handle such responses..."_ - I assume you're referring to Angular's RxJS-based HTTP-client lib? I'll admit I'm not sure you're correct about that (you probably are), but that doesn't matter because [browser-based JS `fetch` does support parsing multipart responses just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067312/multipart-http-response) - so _at most_ you'll need to use a `Promise`-based API instead of Angular's RxJS.

Comment: @Dai I looked into that solution and it seems to be specifically for `multipart/form-data` responses, not `multipart/mixed` (I get a type error when I try it). Since I can't change the return type, I don't think this will work for me.

Comment: I found this - also for Angular: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49098285/159145 - it's still doable, but has some legwork - it looks like you need to temporarily change the content-type to an octet-stream so you can extract each multipart partition by byte-range.

Comment: @Dai Unless I'm misunderstanding something, that answer is either incomplete, incorrect, or outdated. The answerer says they called `response.split()`, which is a string method (and they present a string array). They also say they used the call from the question, which calls `map()` on the result of `get()`, which does not work.

Comment: I think they meant `Blob.slice` **EDIT**: Oh, no, you're right  - damn - well, anyway, it looks like you can do it properly (i.e. 100% binary) with `Blob`. (and I have no idea how on earth their approach is _not_ going to corrupt data...)

Comment: @Dai The entire point of this question is how to get the data from the response into a `Blob` without converting it into a string first.

Comment: You can get a `Blob` from `fetch` easily enough: `await fetch( '/some-multipart/mixed-response' ).then( resp => resp.blob() )` - once you've got that, open it using an `ArrayBuffer` or a `FileReader` and use that API to (safely) search for `--` occurrences as boundary-indicator candidates (as obviously not all `--` chars will be actual boundaries) - and record the offsets as you then do the extra work to confirm each boundary, _then_ you can call `Blob.slice` to split the `multipart/mixed` into separate `Blob` objects.